# ISV or force.com embedded

Tags: force.com, rest-api, isv

My application needs to do an OAuth on behalf of a salesforce customer and do REST API calls to salesforce in order to integrate the Mail experience with salesforce.

Which `Partner program` do i go for? What are the technical distinctions between them?

Comment: Have you tried speaking to SFDC yet? Also, this question seems very broad; are there specific areas of interest?

Comment: Actually, this is it. Our application needs to make REST API calls on behalf of people who already have salesforce accounts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [AppExchange Partner Program Models](http://www.salesforce.com/partners/isv/program-models/). The difference is how the two models work. ISVforce is designed for those creating addon modules for salesforce.com, including integrations with other systems; your clients have to have a salesforce.com license to use your app.

Force.com Embedded is for creating an app that doesn't use any standard CRM features, and doesn't require a separate salesforce.com license (in other words, you are reselling salesforce.com licenses as well licensing your app).

It's hard to find a list of embedded apps, because they are typically rebranded to the company's choosing; even though salesforce.com provides the hosting, services, etc, it acts as though it were fully the third-party's application.

That said, you're obviously looking to use ISVforce, since you want to integrate your system with salesforce.com, and not build an entire app on salesforce.com.